# Discard items when deserializing Json collection with Json.net

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a JSON stream that sends collections looking like this:

```
[{"channel":"24e67e0d-1cad-4cc09e7af8523ef460fe",     
  "op":"private", 
  "origin":"broadcast", 
  "stamp":1388680103991749},
"13886801043507640",
"24e67e0d-1cad-4cc0-9e7a-f8523ef460fe"]
```

The first object is no problem, but the last two ones (`"13886801043507640"` and `"24e67e0d-1cad-4cc0-9e7a-f8523ef460fe"`) make `Json.Net` throw exceptions they don't even follow the format `{field:name,field:name}`.

How can I handle these objects properly (or at least discard them) using `Json.Net`?

Cheers, any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach to extract the object data from the JSON using Json.Net.

First define a class for the object:

```
class Item
{
    public string channel { get; set; }
    public string op { get; set; }
    public string origin { get; set; }
    public long stamp { get; set; }
}
```

Then use Json.Net's LINQ-to-JSON API to parse and filter the array, extracting only the object part:

```
JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);
Item item = array.Children<JObject>().First().ToObject<Item>();
```

If there can be multiple objects, you can get them into a list like this (assuming they all have the same structure):

```
List<Item> items = array.Children<JObject>()
                        .Select(jo => jo.ToObject<Item>())
                        .ToList();
```

Similarly, you can get the string values from the array like this:

```
List<string> strings = array.Children<JValue>()
                            .Select(jv => jv.ToString())
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you Brian for the crystal clear answer, it works like a charm.